Showing a form is closed using integrals
Let $M$ be a manifold and $\omega \in \Omega^r(M)$ be an $r$-form. Suppose $$\int_N \omega = 0$$ for all submanifolds $N$ of dimension $r$ that are diffeomorphic to a sphere. Show that $\omega$ is closed.
This is my attempt: Let $\phi: N \to S^r$ be a diffeomorphism that is orientation preserving, then by Stokes, $$0 = \int_N \omega = \int_{S^r}(\phi^{-1})^*\omega=\int_{D^r}d(\phi^{-1})^*\omega = \int_{D^r}(\phi^{-1})^*d\omega = \int_{\phi^{-1}(D^r)}d\omega.$$
But now I'm confused. First, I'm not even sure if $\phi^{-1}(D^r)$ is well defined -- after all, we only defined $\phi$'s image to be $S^r$.
Even if this is correct, I'm not sure how my results could show that $d\omega = 0$. From this answer, I know that $\omega$ is closed iff its integral against every boundary vanishes. But how do I show that these submanifolds represent "all the boundaries"?

Let's show $d\omega=0$ pointwise. Take a point $x\in M$ and using charts just assume $M=\mathbb{R}^n, \omega \in \Omega^r(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $\int_N \omega = 0$ for all submanifolds $N$ of dimension $r$ that are diffeomorphic to a sphere. We know that $d\omega = \sum f_Idx^I.$ Assume $J=(1,2,\cdots, r+1)$ is such that $f_J> 0$ in a small neighborhood $U$ of $x$. Then in $U \cap\mathbb{R}^r$ take a $(r+1)$-disk $D$ with boundary $S$. Then one can show that $0=\int_S \omega =\int_D d\omega = \int_D f_J >0$ which is a contradiction.

Shouldn't I take a $r+1$ disk in $U\cap \mathbb{R}^{r+1}$?

Also, to be more precise, should I take the disk in $U \cap \mathbb{R}^{r+1}\times {0}^{n-r-1}$? In this way, anything differential form other than J is killed.

Yes that's exactly right
